# working with childrouts: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment

Tags: angular, parent-child, router

i got this error and havn't any idea why. I hope you can help me.
I called the URL with 'Localhost:4200/Admin/Lastrecords'.

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment.'Lastrecords'

parent.module

```html
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    InfoComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    ProtectedComponent,
    DropdownDirective,
    MainComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    routing,],
    ...
    export class AppModule { }
```

**parent.router**

```html
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    {path: '', component: LoginComponent},
    {path: 'Admin', component: DashboardComponent, loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule'},
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES);
```

**child.module**

```html
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DashboardComponent,
    NewAccComponent,
    KeyComponent,
    LastLoginComponent,
    RecordComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    routdash,
    FormsModule,
  ],

   export class AdminModule {

}
```

**child.routing**

```html
const DASH_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: LastLoginComponent, outlet: 'sec'},
  {path: 'Lastlogins', component: LastLoginComponent, outlet: 'sec'},
  {path: 'Lastrecords', component: RecordComponent, outlet: 'sec'},
];

export const routdash = RouterModule.forChild(DASH_ROUTES);
```

Comment: where is router-outlet named sec is placed?

Comment: Why do you have a `component` and `loadChildren` set for the lazy loaded route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that it doesn't work is that you specified a (secondary) outlet in your child routing ('sec') so the URL should be like this:

http://localhost:4200/Admin(sec:Lastrecords)

More info:

https://angular.io/guide/router#secondary-routes